# Using for in CMD

Tags: cmd

Trying to copy several files to another directory:

```
for %I in (file1.txt ^
file2.txt ^
file3.txt) do copy %I c:\somedir\
```

But got error:

```
I was unexpected at this time.
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Are you using this code within a batch file? if so, please add the related tag [tag:batch-file]...

Comment: Running in a command prompt window `for /?` outputs the help which contains already on first output page the paragraph: __To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different from %I.__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 percent characters

```
for %%I in (file1.txt ^
file2.txt ^
file3.txt) do copy %%I c:\somedir\
```